# TypeORM not getting data saved by Prisma

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, prisma

I started migration TypeORM (using Nest.js) to Prisma queries.

At some point I noticed that data saved with Prisma is not accessible by TypeORM.

After saving the data using this Prisma query:

```js
await this.prisma.recipeFilter.create({
      include: { options: true },
      data: {
        label: options.label,
        schemaType: options.schemaType,
        store: { connect: { id: storeId } },
      },
    });
```

I cannot fetch it using TypeORM:

```js
return this.recipeFilterRepository
      .createQueryBuilder('c')
      .where('c.store = :storeId', { storeId })
      .leftJoinAndMapMany('c.options', 'c.options', 'o')
      .loadRelationCountAndMap('c.publishedRecipesCount', 'o.recipes', 'r', (qb) => {
        return qb.andWhere('r.draft = false');
      })
      .getMany();
```

When I run the query that TypeORM generates in the database, I get results:

```
SELECT "c"."id" AS "c_id", "c"."createdAt" AS "c_createdAt", "c"."updatedAt" AS "c_updatedAt", "c"."label" AS "c_label", "c"."schemaType" AS "c_schemaType", "c"."storeId" AS "c_storeId", "o"."id" AS "o_id", "o"."createdAt" AS "o_createdAt", "o"."updatedAt" AS "o_updatedAt", "o"."name" AS "o_name", "o"."slug" AS "o_slug", "o"."filterId" AS "o_filterId" FROM "recipe_filter" "c" LEFT JOIN "recipe_filter_option" "o" ON "o"."filterId"="c"."id" WHERE "c"."storeId" = $1
```

Even after **many minutes of waiting**, the TypeORM query doesn't show results running inside the app, though.

What could be happening here?

Comment: Check your database itself and see if the `recipeFilter` was created. Make sure both ORMs are pointing to the same database & have the same schema

Comment: And of course don't forget to make sure that `storeId` is the same across the create and select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Samathingamajig pointed out, it was indeed a different database!

Wow. Just wow!